# How to get all the values of neighbours around an element in matrix?

Tags: python, python-3.x, list, matrix, nearest-neighbor

I need to get the values of all the neighbors around an element in a matrix in python. Suppose I have a matrix like below,

```py
matrix=[
    [1, 2, 3, 4],
    [5, 6, 7, 8],
    [9,10,11,12]
]
```

For the first element i.e., `matrix[0][0]`, the neighbors are `[2,5,6]`.

For `matrix[0][1]`, the neighbors are `[1,3,5,6,7]`.

For `matrix[0][2]`, the neighbors are `[2,4,6,7,8]`.

For a given element, i need to get these list of values.

I can do the same by comparing i,j values when i=0,j=0 get matrix[0][1], matrix[1][0], matrix[1][1] using switch case and so. But it will become lengthy code. Is there any inbuilt function or any module to make the above task even simpler?

Comment: Are you ok with using numpy?

Comment: So what will be the desired output? A list of lists? What is the input? The whole, err, matrix? The position `(x, y)` of the cell?

Comment: Yes @MadPhysicist . I am ok with using numpy. Is there any simpler solution using numpy that you can suggest?

Comment: @MrT , Input is the index of cell i.e., matrix[row][column] . Output should be a list of numbers which are neighbors of a specific cell.

Comment: @Ssukumar. I'll work something out if I can

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If you don't care about efficiency, use `scipy`:

```
import scipy, scipy.ndimage

def nb_vals(matrix, indices):
    matrix = scipy.array(matrix)
    indices = tuple(scipy.transpose(scipy.atleast_2d(indices)))
    arr_shape = scipy.shape(matrix)
    dist = scipy.ones(arr_shape)
    dist[indices] = 0
    dist = scipy.ndimage.distance_transform_cdt(dist, metric='chessboard')
    nb_indices = scipy.transpose(scipy.nonzero(dist == 1))
    return [matrix[tuple(ind)] for ind in nb_indices]
```

e.g.

```
>>> matrix=[[1,2,3,4],
... [5,6,7,8],
... [9,10,11,12]]
>>>
>>> nb_vals(matrix, [1,1])
[1,2,3,5,7,9,10,11]
```

This is dimension agnostic (works for an arbitrary number of dimensions for the input "matrix") and handles an arbitrary number of indices which you may wish to find neighbours around.

```
>>> arr_shape = (2,3,4,5)
>>> testMatrix = scipy.array(scipy.random.random(arr_shape)*10, dtype=int)
>>> print(testMatrix)
[[[[7 0 0 1 9]
   [9 5 8 5 8]
   [4 0 0 8 0]
   [1 9 1 3 2]]

  [[9 2 3 3 5]
   [2 3 3 7 9]
   [6 5 6 6 2]
   [9 1 1 0 0]]

  [[8 8 5 7 9]
   [9 0 7 7 6]
   [3 8 7 6 4]
   [8 7 5 5 9]]]

 [[[8 9 2 0 0]
   [8 3 5 5 2]
   [4 0 1 0 3]
   [1 0 9 1 3]]

  [[6 9 2 5 2]
   [2 7 5 5 3]
   [6 7 2 9 5]
   [4 2 7 3 1]]

  [[1 7 7 7 6]
   [5 1 4 1 0]
   [3 9 4 9 7]
   [7 7 6 6 7]]]]

>>> nb_vals(testMatrix, [1,2,2,3])
[3, 7, 9, 6, 6, 2, 1, 0, 0, 7, 7, 6, 7, 6, 4, 5, 5, 9, 5, 5, 3, 2, 9, 5, 7, 3, 1, 4, 1, 0, 4, 7, 6, 6, 7]
```

This solution uses a chessboard-type chamfer transform on an image-like binary array mask, where `1` is equal to a white pixel on the mask and `0` is equal to a black pixel (background) to the mask. The chamfer transform calculates the chessboard distance of all white pixels to the background; all pixel locations with a distance calculated as 1 are the neighbours, and the values at these locations on the input array are returned.

Comment: Why not just use a numpy array?

Comment: @MadPhysicist `scipy` and `numpy` arrays are identical..`numpy` is a subset of `scipy`.

Comment: While that's true, you are proposing an incredibly poor use of tools

Comment: @MadPhysicist you might want to elaborate on what you mean. For arrays of an arbitrary number of dimensions and an arbitrary number of elements the user would want to select for neighbours, I believe that doing it this way is much cleaner. As of now I can't see your point  in commenting at all.

Comment: Yeah, sorry about that. I was too caught up in "matrix" to notice the dimension agnostic part. Thought it was overkill. Vote flipped.

Comment: @dROOOze, how could i adjust the code to increase the width of the selected neighbours to 2? So that when selecting [0][0] in OP's matrix the neighbours will be not only [6,2,5] but also [9,10,11,7,3]?

Comment: @intStdu change `nb_indices = scipy.transpose(scipy.nonzero(dist == 1))` to `scipy.transpose(scipy.nonzero((dist <= 2)*(dist > 0)))`

Answer (score 1):

You can build a dictionary of coordinate and corresponding value in the matrix for simpler lookup:

```
matrix=[[1,2,3,4],
        [5,6,7,8],
        [9,10,11,12]]

def get_neighbors(a, b):
  d = {(i, c):matrix[i][c] for i in range(len(matrix)) for c in range(len(matrix[0]))}
  return filter(None, [d.get(i) for i in
    [(a+1, b+1), (a, b+1), (a+1, b), (a-1, b+1), (a-1, b), (a, b-1), (a+1, b-1)]])

cords = [(0, 0), (0, 1), (0, 2)]
results = [get_neighbors(*i) for i in cords]
```

Output:

```
[[6, 2, 5], [7, 3, 6, 1, 5], [8, 4, 7, 2, 6]]
```